# H10 Error - App Crashing, but unclear why

Tags: app, heroku

**The Problem**
I am receiving the H10 error. I've reviewed several stack overflow forums to understand why my app would be crashing with no results. It seems that it may be my Procfile, but this is the recommended structure for Voila apps.

**Background:**

- built using a jupyter notebook + ipywidgets
- deployed as a webapp using Voila
- chose Heroku as hosting site

**Procfile Contents** (*based on voila app recommendation*)

```
web: voila —port=$PORT —no-browser app.ipynb
```

**My Logs with errors**

```
2020-07-20T16:02:43.386188+00:00 app[web.1]:     sys.exit(main())
2020-07-20T16:02:43.386190+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 663, in launch_instance
2020-07-20T16:02:43.386485+00:00 app[web.1]:     app.initialize(argv)
2020-07-20T16:02:43.386501+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/voila/app.py", line 342, in initialize
2020-07-20T16:02:43.386710+00:00 app[web.1]:     raise ValueError('provided more than 1 argument: %r' % self.extra_args)
2020-07-20T16:02:43.386732+00:00 app[web.1]: ValueError: provided more than 1 argument: ['—-port=', '—-no-browser', 'app.ipynb']
2020-07-20T16:02:43.511052+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2020-07-20T16:02:43.546602+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2020-07-20T19:23:06.673968+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=warm-crag-51496.herokuapp.com request_id=a55a0d92-660e-4672-b39f-0a393bad670a fwd="99.156.87.232" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-07-20T19:23:07.271125+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=warm-crag-51496.herokuapp.com request_id=4202a0c1-6750-44f4-ad1a-c4a9ccf391b0 fwd="99.156.87.232" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Comment: This appears at first blush to be an issue specific to Voila, since the exception is thrown within Voila's Python package. I'd recommend reaching out to their support forums.